# How can I create a Dreamweaver "macro" (or command) for repeat use on a list of find & replace terms?

Tags: dreamweaver

I have something similar coded in Excel but I'm looking for something specific to Dreamweaver, if possible.

What I need to do is do a find and replace function, repeatedly during a given week, on HTML code that I am supplied.

I have a list of ~20 terms that I need to find and replace for.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver CC (earlier versions might also) has an option in the find/replace window to save or load a find/replace query.  Should make for short work of your weekly task.